# SVD with missing terms

Tags: algorithm, matrix, machine-learning

Given a real matrix A such that:

- A is symmetric
- All the off-diagonal terms are known and positive
- All the diagonal terms are missing
- Has rank k

I would like to find the best possible completion of A, called Ac, such that (approximately) rank(Ac)=k.

The matrix A can be huge (say n>100000), so I need a method working at most is O(n^3).

To do this, I am thinking at a SVD decomposition with missing terms:

I decompose A, then I recover it by selecting the first k singular vectors.

My question is: there exist any reliable result about SVD when the matrix to be decomposed has missing terms?

Answer (score 0):

There's a close connection between this and the maximum cut problem.  The usual semidefinite relaxation of the maximum cut problem involves minimising the trace of such an Ac subject to the constraint that Ac is positive semidefinite.  I have found [Christoph Helmberg's ConicBundle code](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~helmberg/ConicBundle/) particularly well-suited for computing numerical solutions to these problems.